# get image url inside the content in wordpress?

Tags: php

I want to get the **image_url** from the content.Actually i have done the following code to get the content:

```
$content=$query_val->post_content;
```

i'm getting following as o/p:

---

**"content":"Lorem Ipsum-has been the industry's standard dummy text,Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s..."**

---

When I add the **strip_tags()** like :

```
 $content=strip_tags($query_val->post_content);
```

It will remove all the tags, so that i could not get the image_url which is inside the  tag.

Now I want to get the image url inside the content like:

---

**"content":"Lorem Ipsum-has been the industry's standard dummy text,Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s...image_url:"imageurl"**

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you need to do some regular expression on your post content. Which could be done for example like this:

```
// get the post object
$post = get_post( get_the_ID() );
// we need just the content
$content = $post->post_content;
// we need a expression to match things
$regex = '/src="([^"]*)"/';
// we want all matches
preg_match_all( $regex, $content, $matches );
// reversing the matches array
$matches = array_reverse($matches);
echo '<pre>';
// we've reversed the array, so index 0 returns the result
print_r($matches[0]);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: can we use explode() to achieve this @ialocin?

Comment: not sure I get what you mean @kiruthiga

Comment: okay @ialocin!!You are saying that you not sure about using explode() in this situation right @ialocin?

Comment: @kiruthiga to be honest, I just don't know what you are trying to do with the `explode()`

Comment: `$img_img=explode('<img src="',$content);` shall we use like this

Comment: If you intend to get the image sources that way, it won't work as you might expect - you probably should read up on how explode works. @kiruthiga

Comment: @BilalHussain My pleasure