# Show only picture from post_content in custom RSS file

Tags: rss, post-content

I need to do custom RSS file, And i need to show only pictuer from `post_content`  and put it in `<img>` tag and remove any word, from `post_content` .

So how can i display only images from `post_content` .

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post) {             
$content = get_the_content();
$postOutput = preg_replace('#<a[^>]+>([\r\n|\n]+)?<img[^>]+>([\r\n|\n]+)?<\/a>#','', $post->post_content);
//$postContent = preg_replace("/<a[^>]+\>/i", "", $postOutput);


?>
<article>
        <id></id>
            <title><?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?></title>
            <link><?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?></link>
            <abstract></abstract>
            <body><?php echo '<![CDATA['.$postOutput.'<br/><br/>more: <a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title($post->ID).'</a>'.']]>';  ?></body>
                <date><?php yoast_rss_date( strtotime($post->post_date_gmt) ); ?></date>
                <image_original>....</image_original>
                <image_thumb>....</image_thumb>
                <image_original_alt>....</image_original_alt>
                <slideshow_images>
                    <image>
                        <image_url>.....</image_url>
                        <image_thumb_url>.....</image_thumb_url>
                        <image_alt>.....</image_alt>
                    </image>
                    <image>
                        <image_url>.....</image_url>
                        <image_thumb_url>.....</image_thumb_url>
                        <image_alt>.....</image_alt>
                    </image>
                    <image>
                        <image_url>.....</image_url>
                        <image_thumb_url>.....</image_thumb_url>
                        <image_alt>.....</image_alt>
                    </image>
                </slideshow_images>
</article>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to generate an RSS feed that ONLY shows images?

Comment: yes but not the default rss , i do custom rss file

Comment: Do you already have the custom RSS file that shows all the content? If so, what does your code look like?

Comment: see my edit post

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expression on your post content.Which could be done for example like this:

for [reference](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162402/get-image-url-inside-the-content-in-wordpress)

```
$content = get_the_content();
// we need a expression to match things
$regex = '/src="([^"]*)"/';
// we want all matches
preg_match_all( $regex, $content, $matches );
// reversing the matches array
$matches = array_reverse($matches);
echo '<pre>';
// we've reversed the array, so index 0 returns the result
print_r($matches[0]);
echo '</pre>';
```