# How to search for images and get it's link?

Tags: permalinks, images

I want to make a code to search for images inside the content and get the link for each image to can use it to make another code.

I make this code but I can't complete it:

```
function get_images_link_from_content($content){
    $image_link = '';
    $test = preg_replace('/<p><img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', '<p data-src="'.$image_link.'"><img class="new" src="'.$image_link.'" /></p>', $content);
    return $test;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'get_images_link_from_content');
```

After checking the code you will understand what I need.

NOTE: Content maybe contain more than one image and I want the code to work for all images.

Comment: You might want to have a look here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162402/get-image-url-inside-the-content-in-wordpress#answer-162405

Comment: @PiyushRawat I try this but I think it's not what I need.

Comment: You need urls of every image in a post/page, right??

Comment: @PiyushRawat Yes in the post only using the the_content filter, I need this because I want to add some details for each image like height and width and class because that I need this code.

Comment: @PiyushRawat can you help me about this?